# MSSQL - Join tables and return user based on value in another table column

Tags: sql-server, join

probably a badly worded question so apologies.

I have 3 tables that I want to join together.

I have created an SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1f5ad/2)

What I am wanting, is to compare the `MAXLINEDISCOUNT` from the `linkloads` table to the allowed discounts in the `price_escalation_bands` table.

so in the data, the maxlinediscount of 40 must `match` the next highest discount in the `price_escalation_bands` table where the `customer_band` is the same.

so I want the result to match row 1, where it is bronze and discount is 45. should my `MAXLINEDISCOUNT` be greater than 45, then go to the next highest which could be 50 in this case.

when it matches, return the `fk_salesman_userid` field and match this to the username in the users table.

Obviously, all this data is dynamic so needs to look at next highest...

Currently, it is returning as blank so dont think my syntax is quite correct.

my query is:

```
select price_authorized,load_number,maxlinediscount,customer_band,[price_escalation_bands].fk_salesman_userid,Users.firstname firstname,totalcost,period,creditlimit,currentbalance,customername,totalcubes,treatedcubes,normalcubes,pricingissue from #linkloads
left outer JOIN [price_escalation_bands] on [price_escalation_bands].band=#linkloads.customer_band
AND price_escalation_bands.discount = (
  SELECT top 1 [price_escalation_bands].[discount]
  FROM [price_escalation_bands]
  WHERE [price_escalation_bands].band=#linkloads.customer_band
  AND [price_escalation_bands].[discount]<=#linkloads.maxlinediscount
  ORDER BY [price_escalation_bands].[discount]
)
left outer join Users 
on Users.userid=[price_escalation_bands].fk_salesman_userid
```

Help, appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lists all `price_escalation_bands` entries over the matching limit in `linkloads`:

```
select  u.username
,       peb.band
,       peb.discount
,       ll.maxlinediscount
from    price_escalation_bands peb
join    Users u
on      peb.fk_salesman_userid = u.UserID
join    linkloads ll
on      ll.customer_band = peb.band
where   ll.maxlinediscount < peb.discount
```

[Your SQL Fiddle example with this query.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1f5ad/7/0)

Comment: Thanks. perfect except I want to return only the row with the next lowest discount. so in fiddle, where discount 45. is it a simple min(discount) with a group by clause? Thanks again.